# Where in the Hg code is the command completion implemented?

Tags: python, mercurial

Mercurial has a really nice feature where it allows one to type only what is needed to be unambiguous on the command line, such as:

```
hg pus
```

for pushing, or:

```
hg comm
```

for committing.

I'd love to see this functionality in the likes of Git and Maven, which made me curious as to how it was done. I had a trawl through the code but with not much luck, I found something to do with bash_completion but not for windows.

**Where in the Hg [code](http://selenic.com/hg) is this command completion implemented?**

Comment: In [contrib/bash_completion](http://selenic.com/hg/file/tip/contrib/bash_completion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that does this for commands is the `findpossible` and `findcmd` functions in [mercurial.cmdutil](http://selenic.com/hg/file/bd6aed2ad5ee/mercurial/cmdutil.py#l21). They search the known commands and find the ones that start with what you typed, so `hg pus` finds the `push` command.

For command line options (flags), the normal [getopt module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) lets you shorten, say, `hg log --patch` to `hg log --pat` automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is in `mercurial/cmdutil.py` and the method that does it is called `findpossible`.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, this is done by `bash_completion`

On my system the config for hg is in `/etc/bash_completion.d/mercurial`

Comment: I think that you have not understand his question correctly.  He's not asking about command completion, he's about Mercurial's ability to interpret `hg pus` as `hg push`